# Javascript variable scope when dynamically referencing functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that creates a "proxy" around an object's method. This "proxy" will be used to handle web requests and then call the target method. The proxy function looks similar to this:

```
var proxy = function(c) {
  var proxy = {};
  for(var member in c) {
    var args = c[member].toString().match (/function\s*\w*\s*\((.*?)\)/)[1].split (/\s*,\s*/);
    proxy[member] = function(params) {
      var methodArgs = args.map(function(argName) {
        return params[argName];
      });
      return c[member].apply(c, methodArgs);
    }
  }
  return proxy;
};
```

So if I have this original controller,

```
var c = {
  sum: function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
  },

  multiply: function(x, y) {
    return x * y;
  }
};
```

calling proxy(c) on this will return a proxy object with sum() and multiply() functions. However, because of the scope of the `member` variable in the proxy() function, it will always call the last referenced function in c - in this case, multiply().

```
var cProxy = proxy(c);

//this should call c.sum, but instead calls c.multiply
cProxy.sum({
  x: 3,
  y: 8
});
```

How would I reference the right function in the proxy() function so that the right method gets called?

Comment: why don't you just do `proxy[member]=c[member]`?

Comment: The code above is simplified. In the actual implementation, the proxy would handle web requests and process the request data before calling the original method in c, so that wouldn't be possible. I was able to get it to work using closures as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me, just create a closure for member

```
var proxy = function(c) {
  var proxy = {};
  for(var member in c) {
    !function(member){
        var args = c[member].toString().match (/function\s*\w*\s*\((.*?)\)/)[1].split (/\s*,\s*/);
        proxy[member] = function(params) {
          var methodArgs = args.map(function(argName) {
            return params[argName];
          });
          return c[member].apply(c, methodArgs);
        }
    }(member)
  }
  return proxy;
};



console.log( cProxy.sum({x: 3,y: 8})) // returns 11
console.log( cProxy.multiply({x: 3,y: 8})) //returns 24
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wrap the inside of the loop in a function to create another scope. It looks weird though:

```
    proxy[member] = (function(member) {
        return function(params) {
            var methodArgs = args.map(function(argName) {
                return params[argName];
            });
            return c[member].apply(c, methodArgs);
        };
    })(member);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/t5ovkrw9/

Another way is to use `let member in c`, which creates a slightly smaller scope than `var`, but `let` isn't in most browsers yet.

<s>Yet another way is to use `.bind` to stick arguments or context to a function.</s> That doesn't really work, because you're already using context and arguments.

Comment: Thanks! That would have worked. I chose to use the other answer as the code would have been somewhat cleaner.

Comment: As long as you know what it means. Why is there a `!`? What's this closure business? Why didn't it work in the first place.